# Decimal format in Mathematica exported output

Tags: export, output, output-formatting

I am using `ReadList` to read an input file as `Table` format, and exporting the results. The `input.m` file contains expression (say `exp`). In the file I have the numerical values for the variables.

```
Block[{}, Export["output.m", ReadList["input.m"], "Table"] ]
```

While it is printing small numbers as decimal (e.g. `771640.5749154771`), for bigger numbers it changes to a different format, like `2.8702708449431164e6`.

**Is it possible to keep the decimal format for those large numbers as well?**

There are some solutions using `DecimalForm`, `NumberForm` etc. However I do not know how to implement those in this particular piece of code. Should I enclose the `exp` as `NumberForm[exp, 15]`? Or is there any alternate solution like globally setting `$NumberForm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`"Table"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) export format uses [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) to format content. So, one possibility is to block [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) to something that formats the way you want:

```
Block[{CForm = OutputForm @* (DecimalForm[#,15]&)},
    ExportString[
        {771640.5749154771, 2.8702708449431164*^6},
        "Table"
    ]
]
```

> ```
> "771640.574915477
>  2870270.84494312"
> ```

For Mathematica versions before 11.2, you can use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) with an [`ExponentFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentFunction) option :

```
Block[{CForm = OutputForm @* (NumberForm[#, 15, ExponentFunction->(Null&)]&)},
    ExportString[
        {771640.5749154771, 2.8702708449431164*^6},
        "Table"
    ]
]
```

> ```
> "771640.574915477
>  2870270.84494312"
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow on my mathematica (Mathematica 11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)), `DecimalForm` does not give your output but gives `DecimalForm[2.87027 10^6 , 15]`. But changing to `AccountingForm` gives me your output.

Comment: But then problem with the `AccountingForm` is that it does not recognise negative numbers.

Comment: @Boogeyman See update