# Export table of mixed data without shortened decimal notation?

Tags: export, output-formatting, formatting

My question is similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193334/decimal-format-in-mathematica-exported-output), except the solution presented there does not work in my case since my table contains strings as well as numbers.

I would like to export data such as

```
data = List[List["A",3.0719`*^8],List["B",1.8483`*^8],List["C",6.93`*^6]];
```

to a file. Unfortunately, if I do

```
Export["data.csv",data];
```

the file contains the numbers in a shortened notation, such as `3.0719e8`. I would like the file to save all digits without shortening anything, such that e.g. `3.0719e8` is saved as `307190000`. How should I be doing that in Mathematica 11.3?

Comment: `3.0766e8` is saved as `307190000` does not look right. Are you saying that in your example `3.0719*^8` is saved as `3.0766e8`?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi No, sorry, that was a typo, I've fixed it now. The digits stay the same of course, I'd just like to get rid of the `e` shorthand notation.

Comment: You could e.g. try: Export["filename, ToString@AccountingForm@data]

Comment: @DanielHuber This seems to export a string of the mathematica list, not a csv table.

Comment: If you give your file another extension, e.g. ".dat", you will get: {{A, 307190000.}, {B, 184830000.}, {C, 6930000.}} and if you are not happy with the braces, you say: "Export["d:/tmp/test.dat",  StringDelete[ToString@AccountingForm@data, "{" | "}"]] " . This will give you: A, 307190000., B, 184830000., C, 6930000.

Answer (score 1):

This combination works:

```
ExportString[
 MapAt[NumberForm@AccountingForm@# &, data, 
  Position[data, _Real]], "CSV"]
```

Output:

```
"A",307190000.
"B",184830000.
"C",6930000.
```

Tested on Mathematica 12.2.